# Can't Find and Output Lines From Text files (PYTHON)

Tags: python, text-files, line, strip

I'm trying to take the user's input and compare it with the contents of a text file. They will enter an eight digit number and if that number is present in the txt file then the code should output the line in which it's present on.

```
while (len(code) == 8):

    with open('GTIN Products.txt', 'r') as search:
        for line in search:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if code == line:
                print(line)
```

When the program is run and the number is entered, there is no output. Just blank.

Comment: Does each line contain only an eight digit number and nothing else? Or is there more data? Consider: `"123" == "123ABC"` is False even though one is inside the other.

Comment: There is an eight digit number, a product (i.e "hairbrush") and then a single digit number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1) Are you sure you are correctly opening the file and reading the contents?

2) You are asking the 8 character code to be identical to the line, meaning the line must also be 8 characters. Is that the case? You may want to try

```
if code in line:
    print(line)
    break
```

Comment: "if code in line:" worked thank you, silly me. Although, it repeatedly prints the line rather than just once... do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: Please provide the code that reproduces the problem; that includes the data file.

Comment: Check my edit, and if this worked for you, please mark it as the answer :).

Comment: The devil is in the details :).